# perl match specific number and word

Tags: perl

Given a file include:

```
const users = [
  {
    name: 'Jeff',
    age: 52,
    gender: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Andy',
    age: 25,
    gender: 'male'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sarah',
    age: 30,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    name: 'Phoebe',
    age: 21,
    gender: 'female'
  },
  {
    name: 'Doris',
    age: 81,
    gender: 'female'
  }
];
```

And i am trying to match "age with gender is male",but i don't know why my code cant match this. But it works on "https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/24"

```
while ($line = <FILE>){
    if($line =~ /age:(.*)\,\s*gender: 'male'\}/g){
        print "$1\n"; #output display number only
        print "$line\n";
    }   
}
```

should match like this:

```
age: 52,
gender: 'male'

age: 25,
gender: 'male'
```

Comment: `<>` reads a line at a time by default, looks like you're expecting it to read more than one.

Comment: Given the structure of your data, it might be easier to do a bit of formatting (like `s/^.*?=\s*//` to remove the `const users = ` (adapt that depending on your files...)) and to use the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module instead of using regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made one large mistake and one smaller one.

Mainly, you seem to have forgotten that `<FILE>` will read in a single line from your file. And none of the individual lines from your file will match your regex. You could verify this by printing the value of `$line` inside your loop.

The simplest way to fix this is to use the `$/` variable. `$/` is Perl's "input record separator". It contains the text string that Perl uses to determine the end of a record when reading from a file. The default value is `\n` (which is why `<...>` reads a line at a time), but we can change it to make it more useful.

```
$/ = "},\n";
```

Now, if you print `$line`, you'll get something far more useful.

But the code still doesn't work. Because of the small error in your regex.

Your regex looks like this:

```
age:(.*)\,\s*gender: 'male'\}
```

It assumes that the closing `}` directly follows the string `male`. But that's not the case - there's a newline between them. If you change the regex to account for this, then it will work:

```
age:(.*)\,\s*gender: 'male'\s*\}
```

Your code now works, but parsing code like this is rather fragile. You'd probably be better advised to remove the `const users =` and then parse the rest using a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Perl-oneliner also. I used \x27 hex for matching single quotes. Check this out

```
> perl -ne ' BEGIN {$/="}"} { print $x if /(age:(.+?).*(gender:\s\x27male\x27))/osmg and $x="$1\n" } ' const.txt
age: 52,
    gender: 'male'
age: 25,
    gender: 'male'
>
```

or more compact one.

```
> perl -ne ' BEGIN {$/="}"} { print $x if /age:.*gender:\s\x27male\x27/osmg and $x="$&\n" } ' const.txt
age: 52,
    gender: 'male'
age: 25,
    gender: 'male'
>
```

Comment: You are not helping the OP, nor anyone who may come later with a similar issue. There are decent chances that his code snippet is part of a larger program, in which case your answer isn't useful. Yes, writing one-liners is somewhat fun, but I don't think this is a good answer.

Comment: @Dada.. the answer is specific to this input file. I never claimed that it is a generic solution..The OP never mentioned what you are saying as the requirement and is fine with my answer..please understand the context and then downvote.. or give your best answer before you downvote other's.

Comment: Thing is, anyone who is sufficiently proficient in Perl to understand your one-liner wouldn't have had the problem in the first place. Also, I don't complain about the fact that your answer is specific to this input file, but rather that your answer assumes that the OP only wanted to do the 4 lines of code he wrote. In all likelihood, it's part of a bigger program, and once a retrieves the ages/gender, he does something with them.

Comment: And regarding your "give your best answer before you downvote other's": this is in no case a rule of SO, and makes no sense imo. I can think your answer isn't good without writing one of my own. But if you care: I read the question, thought about it, wrote a comment suggesting a better way to deal with the issue, read Dave's answer, upvoted it. So I think I understand well enough the context. And after that, I saw your answer, and wrote my comment explaining why I disagree. => I don't think my methodology is wrong and that I shouldn't have downvoted.

Comment: Your assumption might be equally wrong.. the snippet could be part of a large bash program where the OP uses perl script to extract the age and gender.. In that case my answer fits well and that is the reason the OP has upvoted..